# how to display checked or checked in edit data php?

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

i have

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function setCheckboxes3(act) {
        var e = document.getElementsByClassName('names');
        var elts_cnt  = (typeof(e.length) != 'undefined') ? e.length : 0;
        if (!elts_cnt) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < elts_cnt; i++) {
            e[i].checked = (act == 1 || act == 0) ? act : (e[i].checked ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(1);" class="chkmenu">Semua</a> |
<a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(0);" class="chkmenu">Tidak Satupun</a> |
<a href="javascript:setCheckboxes3(2);" class="chkmenu">Balik Pilihan</a><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[1]" class="names" value="1" />Pembinaan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[2]" class="names" value="1" />Intelijen<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[3]" class="names" value="1" />Pengawasan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[4]" class="names" value="1" />Pidum<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[5]" class="names" value="1" />Pidsus<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[6]" class="names" value="1" />Datun<br/>
```

how to display checked or checked in edit data ???
(make array if 0=not checked and if 1=checked)

example 100001

```
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[1]" class="names" value="1" checked="checked" />Pembinaan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[2]" class="names" value="1" />Intelijen<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[3]" class="names" value="1" />Pengawasan<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[4]" class="names" value="1" />Pidum<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[5]" class="names" value="1" />Pidsus<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[6]" class="names" value="1" checked="checked" />Datun<br/>
```

Comment: This seems like JavaScript problem rather than PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a checkbox is not checked it's key will not appear in the result data. I think a better approach is this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[]" value="Pembinaan" checked="checked" />Pembinaan
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[]" value="Intelijen" />Intelijen
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[]" value="Pengawasan" />Pengawasan
<input type="checkbox" name="listBidang[]" value="Datun" checked="checked" />Datun
```

Now your data should look like:

```
$_GET["listBidang"]; // array("Pembinaan", "Datun");
```

The empty bracket notation (`listBidang[]`) will dynamically build the set for you. Omitting any unchecked values.

If there are no values checked `$_GET["listBidang"]` will **not** be set. You might expect an empty array, but alas. So make sure you use `isset`, `empty` or `array_key_exists` to check if it's there before trying to read it.

Comment: my mistake, `$bid = '';
            $bidang = $_POST['listBidang'];
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
                if ($bidang[$i])
                    $bid.='1';
                else
                    $bid.='0';
            }` how to explode an array value when 0=not checked and 1=checked, thank's before